# Primality test $n \mid F_{n+1}+F_{n-1}-1$

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, primality-test

I have found information and references about the Fibonacci primality test:

$$n \mid F_{n-\left(\frac{5}{n}\right)}$$

but not about the following primality test:

$$n \mid F_{n+1}+F_{n-1}-1$$

Which I found holding true for the first $5000$ primes (see [see here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FractionalPart%28%5BF_%28Prime%5Bn%5D%2B1%29%2BF_%28Prime%5Bn%5D-1%29-1%5D%2FPrime%5Bn%5D%29%2C+n+%3D+1+to+5000)), while for $n \le 2000$ there is only one pseudoprime $n = 705$ (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FractionalPart%28%5BF_%28n%2B1%29%2BF_%28n-1%29-1%5D%2Fn%29%2C+n%3D705) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BFractionalPart%28%5BF_%28n%2B1%29%2BF_%28n-1%29-1%2BBoole%5BPrimeQ%5Bn%5D%5D%5D%2Fn%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+2%2C+2000%7D%5D)).

Originally I saw it as $n \mid F_{2n} - F_{n}$ and then replaced $F_{2n}$ to get the above.

Somebody can give me any reference and/or literature about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now found that the wikipedia page [Lucas pseudoprime](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_pseudoprime) has all the references where it talks about "an alternative definition of Fibonacci pseudoprime" and especially the article:
Adina Di Porto; Piero Filipponi (1989). "More on the Fibonacci Pseudoprimes" (PDF). Fibonacci Quarterly. 27 (3): 232–242 (see [link](https://www.fq.math.ca/Issues/27-3.pdf)) has the test ((1.16) at page 234):
$$n \mid L_n - 1$$
Which is the same as the above expressed with Lucas numbers.